# css and other in gnu microhttpd

Tags: c++, css, gnu

i work on a soft using the gnu microhttpd library and it's working fine.
Anyway to made my html output human-friendly, i want to use css and so one.
sound like a made an error but i don't see :

so, if someone could help.

```
 string sPage;
    sPage = "<html><head><link rel = \"stylesheet\" type = \"text/css\" href = \"./template.css\" /></head><body style=\"background-color:red><a href=\"../test1.htm\">Link to this folder</a><div class=\"flex-container\"><div>Le processus " + Process
    + " n\'est pas actif, impossible de se connecter</div></div><IMG src=\"../images/TrafficLights.png\"></body></html>";

    struct MHD_Response *response;
    int ret;

    //response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (page),(void*) page, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
    response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (sPage.c_str()),(void*) sPage.c_str(), MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
    ret = MHD_queue_response (connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
    MHD_destroy_response (response);

    return ret;
```

Comment: It is a mistake to store `sPage.c_str()` for later use; it becomes invalid when `sPage` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [MHD_queue_response](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/html_node/microhttpd_002dresponse-create.html):

> [mode] memory management options for buffer; use MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT if the buffer is static/global memory, use MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_FREE if the buffer is heap-allocated and should be freed by MHD and MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY if the buffer is in transient memory (i.e. on the stack) and must be copied by MHD;

So either define `sPage` with its full contents somewhere statically, or keep your stack allocated `sPage` but set the mode to `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY`.

Comment: keep your stack allocated sPage but set the mode to MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY :

Comment: Did you mean to ask a follow-up question?

Comment: i try but without success : <code>
    response = MHD_create_response_from_buffer (strlen (sPage.c_str()),(void*) sPage.c_str(),MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY);</code>

Comment: Edit your question with a stack trace of how this solution crashes, then.

Comment: no crash but can't add pictures or external css link. It doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a useless diagnostic, sorry. Do you not get the specified HTML back from a HTTP request? Does it not contain the `<link>` tag? Does the follow-up request of the CSS file fail? Did you expect the CSS file to be magically inlined into your response? We need actual and expected results to be able to help you.

Comment: All the follow up seems not to work. I presume it's because i miss to defined the base directory on my server but i couldn't find the parameter for that.

Comment: I don't think libmicrohttpd will serve static files by itself. You will have to write a handler that matches the css file you're trying to serve.